# URLLoader Event.COMPLETE is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

I'm trying to add a Listener for `URLLoader` in Haxe but it seems that this trigger is not working (or, at least, never called). I checked for possible solutions but nothing seems to help me

```
var urlLoader : URLLoader;

public function new(apiURL) {
    super();
    this.urlLoader = new URLLoader();
    this.urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(apiURL + "?cachebust=" + Math.floor(100000+900000*Math.random()))); // for cache...
    // json loader
    load_json(apiURL);
}

public function load_json(apiURL:String){
    this.urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    this.urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
    this.urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    this.urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

private function onComplete(e:Event) {throw "complete";}
private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent) {throw "progree";}
private function onSecurityError(e:SecurityErrorEvent) {throw "error";}
private function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent) {throw "io error";}
```

None of those triggers is called, it seems that the application just ignores that step.

i'm sure that `apiUrl` is not `null` and it contains an url like `localhost/json.php`. I am working locally.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Add those event listeners before you call `urlLoader.load`. By the time `load_json` executes, the `URLLoader` might already be finished with its work, but your event listeners aren't set yet.

Comment: Gumma Mocciaro: Welcome to Stack Overflow I have tidied up the formatting of the question, you can place variable names and values in backticks (`) to put them in a monospace font, you also don't need to include <code> tags as long as you indent your code by four characters.

Comment: @DodgerThud i added the `urlLoader.load` call after all the triggers but nothing happens. now i have something like 

`this.urlLoader = new URLLoader();
this.urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
this.urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(apiURL + "?cachebust=" + Math.floor(100000+900000*Math.random())));`

Comment: add the other listeners as well so that you get errors. Also, could please place a trace statement around that code somewhere? like above the `this.urlloader = new URLLoader()` line? Because I think this constructor never gets called because you gave it the name 'new', which is not allowed afaik.

Comment: the constructor is surely called because i have other stuff in it (i found this kind of declaration on haxe documentation, even if i don't know if is right) anyway, the "new" method is called 100% as constructor

Comment: Are you sure about that `new`? That is hardly believable. It is supposed to be a keyword. Can you point to the documentation, please?

Comment: random example -> http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-instance.html

in this case you'll call new Point(x,y);

point n° 5 : followed by a special function field named new, which is the constructor of the class. or i'm missing something?
Anyway, as i said before, i have other stuff and declarations inside this "new" method that are working great

Comment: The code you have provided is part of a class file. Can you provide how you are creating an instance of this class and perhaps this class as a whole?

Comment: Additionally, I think you have removed code from your example that is needed to determine the issue. You are passing in an `apiURL` to the `load_json` function, but never using it. I suspect there is code you may have removed to simplify for your example. In any case, you really should performing all of your `addListener` functions right after you create the `URLLoader` and before you call the `load` function.

Comment: Additional things to verify, just to be certain...Place a trace within `load_json` to make sure it is getting called. Place a trace within your handler functions such as `onComplete` to make sure they are not getting called. Set your handler functions to be public (just for testing) to make sure something funny isn't happening.

Comment: ok, mistery solved, seems that adobe doesn't allow to call a `localhost` file (as `localhost/json.php` due to security reason, so i added a rule on my `/etc/hosts` for my local ip calling it `test.com` and asking for `http://test.com/json.php` now is working 100% (i think that haxe with IntelliJ is not 100% debugging my code), thanks to everyone for your time anyway!